# tailwind custom breakpoints removes colors

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, cdn

I added a custom break point, but whenever I do this I lose the custom colors I made too. Am I doing something wrong here? For reference I'm using the cdn link not npm hence why you won't see module exports. This is a not for a prod ENV.

[image]

```
tailwind.config = {
            theme: {
   

        screens: {
  iphone: '360px',
  ...defaultTheme.screens,
},

                extend:{
                    colors: {
                        green: "#02594c",
                        grey: "#333",
                        yellow: "#fe0",
                        purple: "#5F3DC4",
                          orange: "#ff9800"
                    },
                    
                            
                    fontSize: {
                lg2:'1.1875rem',
                remtwo: '2rem',
            },
            margin: {
                xxl:'34rem',
                xxl2:'37rem',
                xxl3:'40rem',
                xxl4:'45rem',
                xxl5:'50rem',
                xxl6:'55rem',
                xxl7:'60rem',
                xxl8:'65rem',
                xxl9:'70rem',
            },
            gap:{
                
                110: '23rem',
                120: '27rem',
                130: '30rem',
                135: '32rem',
                140: '33rem'
            },
            fontFamily:{
              arial: ['arial']
            },
            height:{
                xxl:'25rem',
                xxl2: '27rem',
                xxl3: '30rem',
                xxl4: '32rem',
                xxl5: '34rem'
            },
            width:{
                xl: '25rem',
                xxl:'30rem',
                xxl2: '37rem',
                xxl3: '38rem'
            },
            borderWidth:{
                xl: '323px',
                xxl: '400px',
            },
                },
                
            },
        };
```

[enter link description here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#adding-smaller-breakpoints)